# Ajax и передача разных типов данных

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Доброго времени суток! Возникла небольшая проблема. Есть ajax запрос и нужно в нем отправить две переменные в php файл.

```
function order_order(formId,prizeId) {
            var data = $(formId).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../logic/cart.php',
                data: data + "id=" + prizeId,
                success: function(txt){
                    alert('success');
                    $('.cart_content').html(txt);
                    $('#order').css('display','block');
                }
            });
        }
```

Собсно в чем проблема: переменная data хранит в себе данные с формы, а переменная id просто число. `data: data + "id=" + prizeId` данная конструкция не срабатывает. `data:{data, id:prizeId}` - тоже не работает, как и `data:{data, "id":prizeId}`  На просторах интернета не нашел ответа на свой вопрос. Кто-нибудь подскажите как правильно сформулировать запрос. Заранее спасибо!)

Comment: Погляди - что-то похожее я задавал:

http://hashcode.ru/questions/351470/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для единственного параметра, значение которого всегда целое число, достаточно

```
data: data + "&id=" + prizeId
```

В чуть более общем случае, когда в значении параметра может быть строка с пробелами и др. спецсимволами, лучше использовать [`jQUery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/):

```
data: data + "&" + jQuery.param( {id: prizeId})
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо большое !) Вчера пол интернета перевернул )